# address allocation in linux : possible over lap?

Tags: linux, memory, overlapping

I am trying to check if my program is assigning memory correctly -

so i have series of pointers of different types,

pData1 = 0x844c458 ( result of malloc(5 * size of (double*))

pData2 = 0x844c470 (result of malloc (10 *size of (double*));

pData3 = 0x844c3a0(result of malloc(44 * size 0f (double*));

pData4 = 0x844c358

So i think double = 8 bytes , 5 *8 = 40 bytes, which means first two addresses will overlap and similarly last two ?

I am getting invalid free, so i am investigating a memory corruption in my code so trying to find where this might be happening.

-----Edit ------- Adding code details

THis is the struct -

```
struct _ELEMENT
 {
 short s;
 char arr[20];
 int size;
 void *ptr1;
 void *ptr2;
 }ELEMENT;
```

There are two classes Parent and Derived ( child of Parent)

```
Class Parent
{ 
protected:
int size;
 ELEMENT *ele1;
ELEMENT *ele2;

 public:
 void func();
...
 }
Class Child::public Parent
{
 int a,b,c;
 }
 Parent::Parent()
 {
  ele1 = NULL;
  ele2= NULL;
 }

  Parent::~Parent()
  {
   for (int i =0; i< size; i++)
   {
    free(ele1[i].p1);
    free(ele2[i].p1);
   }
   free(ele1);
   free(ele2); 
  }
  Child::Child()
  {
   a=0;...
  }
  Child::~Child()
  {
   for (int i =0; i< size; i++)
   {
    free(ele1[i].p1);
    free(ele2[i].p1);
   }
   free(ele1);
   free(ele2); 
  }

 Parent::func ()
{
 ele1 = (ELEMENT*)malloc (n * sizeof(ELEMENT));   
 ele2 = (ELEMENT*)malloc (n* sizeof(ELEMENT));

  for (int i =0; i <somenumber; i++)
 {
   ...some processing...
   ele1[i].size = n;
   ele2[i].size = x;
   ele1[i].p1 = malloc (ele1[i].size);
   ele2[i].p1 = malloc(ele2[i].size);
  }
 }

main ()
{
  Parent *p;
  CHild *c;

  p = new Parent();
  c= new Child();

  p->func();
  c->func();

  delete(p);
 delete(c);
}
```

The _glibc:invalid free comes at first free of parent destructor. This code was working fine in SOlaris for years but porting it in linux is giving this issue...

Thanks!

Comment: what size do you think the size of a double pointer is?

Comment: As posed, this isn't really a question that can be answered. I put some "general thoughts" in an answer below - but you really should try to post an actual question ("here is code, this is what the pointers look like, how did that happen?")

Comment: Memory obtained by malloc will not overlap - unless you free in the meantime.

Comment: the reason I ask is that x70-x58=x18 (dec 24) and 5*4 = 20 so there's no overlap there.  xc358 is what? and what does it have to do with xc3a0? without seeing the whole code (as mentioned above) there isn't enough here to answer.

Comment: Is this a 32 bit or 64 bit machine. It might affect the size of pointers. As @KevinDTimm asked - what is `sizeof(double*)`? I had not noticed the `*`...

Comment: So you are using 32 bit hence sizeof(double*)=4. Ok, but what's the problem now?

Comment: PS: Why not have efence or valgrind do the work for you?

Comment: So, why does this look nothing like the original question?

Comment: Well pData1 addresses that i have pasted is the ele1[i].p1 and ele2[i].p1 values ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that your program is allocating memory correctly, the first problem you had/have is that you don't know the size of your data types and so your computations are incorrect.

If you would post your code and the actual errors that you are getting, it's possible that we can figure this out.  As it is, the deep problem of `invalid free` cannot be answered.

To whom it may concern, is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: ... and confusing `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(double*)`.

Comment: @Axel - yes, that's what I'm saying with 'not knowing the size of datatypes' :) leading to the confusion with those 2 sizeof's

Answer (score 1):

1. `sizeof(double)` is 8 bytes and `sizeof(double*)` is 4 (on your 32 bit system).
2. Memory obtained by `malloc` will not overlap unless freed in the meantime.
3. Use a memory debugger such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that way... how did you end up with these pointers? In principle it's OK to have different pointers pointing to the same space - you just shouldn't be "freeing" except from a pointer that was assigned with `malloc` (or `calloc`). The glibc actually keeps some data "just below the pointer" that tells it how big the block is etc, so it can free "cleanly". If you change the value of the pointer, you can't "free part of a block" since the information about how big the block is isn't available (only if the pointer is unchanged).  Could that be the source of your problem?

Comment: note the 4 byte difference between 0x58 + 0x18 & the amount of memory actually allocated (0x14).  There's the data `just below the pointer`.